# Error: EntityType does not declare a navigation property with the name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to calculate budget minus expenses and display it in a view.  I have the calculations working but am stuck on how to incorporate the results in my view.  Right now I am getting the error:

> `EntityType TETSModel.Project` does not declare a navigation property with the name data.

Without the statement `projects = from s in db.Projects.Include(p => data) select s;` this works fine but does not display the balances.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

From the controller:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var data = (from p in db.Projects
                join ex in db.ExpenseItems on p.ProjectKEY equals ex.ProjectKEY
                group ex by p into exgroup
                select new Classes.Budget
                {
                ProjectKEY = exgroup.Key.ProjectKEY,
                OverallBudgetMinusExpenses = exgroup.Key.OverallTechnologyBudget - exgroup.Sum(g => g.ExpenseAmount),
                CurrentBudgetMinusExpenses = exgroup.Key.CurrentPeriodBudget - exgroup.Sum(g => g.ExpenseAmount)
                    });
    var projects = from s in db.Projects.Include(p => p.ContractType).Include(p => p.Division)
               select s;
    projects = from s in db.Projects.Include(p => data)
               select s;
    return View(projects.ToList());
}
```

In the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TETS_DAL.Project>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Projects";
}
<h2>All Projects</h2>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New Project", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <!--@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectKEY)-->
        </th>
        <th>Project<br />
            Number
        </th>
        <th>Office
        </th>
        <th>Project<br />
            Description
        </th>
        <th>Start<br />
            Date
        </th>
        <th>End<br />
            Date
        </th>
        <th>Current<br />
            Period<br />
            Start
        </th>
        <th>Current<br />
            Period<br />
            End
        </th>
        <th>Total<br />
            Budget
        </th>
        <th>Total<br />
            Budget<br />
            Balance
        </th>
        <th>Current<br />
            Budget
        </th>
        <th>Current<br />
            Budget<br />
            Balance
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ProjectKEY)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Division.DivisionName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectDescription)
            </td>
            <td>
                @String.Format("{0:d}", item.StartDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @String.Format("{0:d}", item.OverallEndDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @String.Format("{0:d}", item.CurrentPeriodStartDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @String.Format("{0:d}", item.CurrentPeriodEndDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OverallTechnologyBudget)
            </td>
            <td>
                @*  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpenseItem.ExpenseAmount)*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentPeriodBudget)
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProjectKEY }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ProjectKEY }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Expenses", "Index", "ExpenseItem", new { projectSearchString = item.ProjectNumber }, null)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

}

The Budget Class:

```
public class Budget
{
[Key]
public int ProjectKEY { get; set; }
public decimal? OverallBudgetMinusExpenses { get; set; }
public decimal? CurrentBudget { get; set; }
public decimal? CurrentBudgetMinusExpenses { get; set; }
public decimal? OverallBudget { get; set; }
}
```

Project Model:

```
namespace TETS_DAL
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        this.ExpenseItems = new HashSet<ExpenseItem>();
    }

    public int ProjectKEY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DivisionKEY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ContractTypeKEY { get; set; }
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OverallEndDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CurrentPeriodStartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CurrentPeriodEndDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> OverallTechnologyBudget { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CurrentPeriodBudget { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Archive { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public byte[] ts { get; set; }

    public virtual ContractType ContractType { get; set; }
    public virtual Division Division { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExpenseItem> ExpenseItems { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the `Project` model?

Comment: Project model is posted per your request

Comment: just like the error is telling you... your `Project` class does not have a `data` navigation property.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbee and have no idea what that means.  I looked it up and still am unclear what I should do.

Comment: Your `Project` class does not have a property called `data`. This line `from s in db.Projects.Include(p => data)` is going to look for a property called `data` in your `Project` class.

Answer (score 9):

You have these lines:

```
var projects = from s in db.Projects.Include(p => p.ContractType).Include(p => p.Division)
           select s;
projects = from s in db.Projects.Include(p => data)
           select s;
```

Why are you assigning to the variable `projects` twice?

Also, as noted in the comments to your question, the lambda expression `p => data` says, "For each `p`, return its `data` property."  But, based on the error message you're getting, the `Project` type doesn't have a property called `data`.  That's why you're getting the error message.

But I think I see what you're trying to do.  You want to have both the `Project` object and the `Budget` items from the variable data in your model?  You probably need to define yet another class that includes a Project property AND a Budget property:

```
public ProjectViewModel
{
    Project Project { get;set;}
    Budget Budget { get;set;}
}
```

... and write a line or two of LINQ to create a collection of `ProjectViewModel` objects from `projects` and `data`, joining (I assume) on the `ProjectKEY` property that they have in common.

Comment: +1.  I wonder if the OP is confused that you can specialise queries, e.g...  do the initial `var projects = blah` and later, based on a condition, specialise it further: `if(some_condition_only_op_knows()) projects = projects.Where(p => *another condition*);`.. but you're probably right. LINQ training needed? :)

Comment: The additional class is the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.  Thank you!